# Flatten vs SumList Function

Tags: python, flatten

I wrote a flatten function that turns a nested list into one list

```
def flatten(lst, new=[]):
    for i in lst:
        if type(i)==list:
            flatten(i)
        else:
            new+=[i]
    return new
```

I tried using the same logic to make a function that adds up all positive numbers found in the nested list.

```
def posSum(lst, Sum=0):
    for i in lst:
        if type(i)==list:
            posSum(i)
        else:
            if i > 0:
                Sum+=i
    return Sum
```

This returns 0. Why is it the "new" variable gets updated in flatten, but Sum doesn't get updated in posSum? I even put a print statement in my else clause to see if I could print out all the "i"s, which works. I tried putting a return for posSum instead of just calling it, but then it only calculates the sum for the first element since it breaks the loop. How can I get around this in one function, as opposed to me flattening the list, and then going through the new list?

Comment: Try i +=  posSum(i) rather than just posSum(i)

Comment: @vaultah while the mutable default argument is a bug waiting to happen here, the actual reason the OP isn't seeing what they expect is because they don't capture the result of the recursive call.

Comment: @LeopoldVonBuschLight close, but it should be `Sum += posSum(i)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Oops, you're right. Good catch!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga the mutability of `new` is the reason the first function works as expected.

Comment: @vaultah yes, I see your point, OK, if you want to re-close with that dupe, but I think there *must* be a better one somewhere... hard to find since there are about a million questions about "recursive sum" in the Python tag...

Comment: @vaultah yes, sorry, I jumped the gun.